# How to solve send email action in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Below is my JSP code use to reserve restaurant table. I want to send email to user when table is reserve successful, but it cannot send email to user. I already try many method to solve it but it also return me an error message with email cannot be send.

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="booking.Bean.Login"%>
<%@page import="booking.DB.OrderDB"%>
<%@page import="booking.Bean.Order"%>
<%@page import="booking.Wrapper.Wrapper"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Add Order JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
    <ul>

                <li class="menuitem"><a href="aboutC.jsp">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="clientsC.jsp">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="contactC.jsp">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="login.jsp">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">

            <div id="leftmenu_top"></div>

            <div id="leftmenu_main">
                <jsp:include page="orderMenu.jsp" />
            </div>

            <div id="leftmenu_bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="content_top"></div>
            <div id="content_main">
                <h2>Order Status</h2>
                <%

                    String OrderCustId = request.getParameter("OrderCustIDtxt");
                    String OrderDate = request.getParameter("OrderDatetxt");
                    String OrderTime = request.getParameter("OrderTimetxt");
                    String OrderSeat = request.getParameter("OrderSeattxt");
                    //char BStatus = request.getParameter("OrderStatustxt");
                    //String userId = request.getParameter("txtUserId");
                    String custName = request.getParameter("textCustName");
                    String cEmail = request.getParameter("textCustEmail");
                    String cPhoneNo = request.getParameter("textCustContactNo");

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date = sdf.parse(OrderDate);


                    Order order = new Order();
                    order.getOrderId();
                    order.setCustId(OrderCustId);
                    order.setStaffId("2000");
                    order.setOrderDate(date);
                    order.setOrderTime(OrderTime);
                    order.setOrderSeat(OrderSeat);
                    order.setBStatus('A');
                    order.setOCustName(custName);
                    order.setcOEmail(cEmail);
                    order.setcOPhoneNo(cPhoneNo);

                    OrderDB orderDB = new OrderDB();
                    int seatAvaliable=orderDB.checkSeat(order);
                    if(seatAvaliable<35){                   
                        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
                        int status = wrapper.addOrder(order);

                        if (status > 0) {
                            out.print("<center><h5><font color='blue'>Successful Place Order</font></h5></center>");
                    %>
                    <br>
                    <table border="0" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" bgcolor="lightgrey">Display Details Added New
                                Order</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order ID:</td>
                            <td><%=order.getOrderId()%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Customer ID:</td>
                            <td><%=OrderCustId%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order Date:</td>
                            <td><%=date%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order Time:</td>
                            <td><%=OrderTime%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order Seat:</td>
                            <td><%=OrderSeat%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Customer Name:</td>
                            <td><%=custName%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Customer Email:</td>
                            <td><%=cEmail%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Customer Contact No:</td>
                            <td><%=cPhoneNo%></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Back"
                                onclick="history.go(-1)" /></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                    <%
                        String result;
                        String to = cEmail; //ur client email
                        String from = "dasreg10@gmail.com"; //ur email address

                        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";         //for yahoo smtp.mail.yahoo.com == 465
                        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
                        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
                        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","587");
                        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

                        try{
                            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

                            //This is your email subject
                            message.setSubject("L'eo Cafe Booking Success");
                            //This is the actual msg
                            message.setText(custName+" "+"Your table has been reserved at "+date+" "+OrderTime);
                            // Send message
                            Transport.send(message);
                            result = "Booking information sent successfully....";
                        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
                            mex.printStackTrace();
                            result = "Error: unable to send message....";
                        }
                        out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
                    %>
                    <%

                        } else {
                            out.print("<center><h5><font color='red'>Failed to Place Order</font></h5></center>");
                        }
                    %>
                    <br>
                    <%
                        }
                    else{
                        out.print("<center><h5><font color='red'>Booking Full!!!</font></h5></center>");    
                        }
                    %>



            </div>
            <div id="content_bottom"></div>
            <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the exception that get from the system:

```
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ay5sm8087291pab.1

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.addOrderJSP_jsp._jspService(addOrderJSP_jsp.java:256)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is for my final year academic project.

Comment: I do not see user and pass for authentication.

Comment: Please do not reuse/edit an existing question for a completely different problem. This would invalidate all answers and makes the whole question+answers confusing for future readers which haven't read the original question before the edit. Instead, just post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The mail server you are connecting to is not running or is configured to refuse connections in this scenario. You might not even have a mail server installed on localhost

You can confirm this by telnet-ing to port 25 on localhost.

Start the mail server or check the configuration or alternatively, use another host.

Comment: The question has changed enough that it warrants a new question, with a closure of this one. Please be careful when changing things to that degree in future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that doing `MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);` would get the appropriate smtp server in the MimeMessage. You should set it by hand:

```
message.addHeader("mail.smtp.host", host);
message.addHeader(""mail.smtp.port","587");
```

and do it for every header. Alternatively you could create an instance of Transport, see [here](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.html)

**EDIT**

Seeing your trace, I think you want to connect to `gmail smtp`. Doing so, you need to put your password in the code, which you want to avoid. Maybe try to install a local smtp server?

Comment: i try to add password but it still cannot work. how to install local smtp server?